# How concatenate more values inside a variable with values inside braces(Curly brackets)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 3 variables with with different values, i check an if statement if it works or not, if it works i concatenate the values, For example

```
var VAX = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
if(1 = 1) {
var VAX .= {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; //AS I KNOW IN PHP [.=]
}
if(x = y) {
var VAX .= {11, 12, 13}; //AS I KNOW IN PHP [.=]
}
```

and the final result i want to make is

```
var VAX = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
```

is that possible using JavaScript?

To be used in AJAX data here

`$.get('page.php', {data}, function(){})`

Comment: That's not valid Javascript to start with. But assuming you mean to start with *arrays* then the function you are looking for is [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: Do you mean to concat two array? For array you can use `concat()`.

Comment: In JS array and object are not the same, `[]` are used for ordered without key lists (in fact, they have index as key: `0, 1, 2, ..`). Ex: `let arr = [1, 'ab', 'foo']`. And object, who are not ordered but have a `string-key`, like so: `let obj = {foo: 'bar', count: 4}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign` to  "merge" two objects. For example:

```js
var obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2};
var obj2 = {c: 3};

var obj3 = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
console.log(obj3);
```

However, these "objects" you showed are not valid objects. In objects, we have `keys` and `values`, and there is no order for those keys. Maybe you need arrays, and you can concatenate them with `concat`:

```js
var VAX = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
VAX = VAX.concat([6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
VAX = VAX.concat([11, 12, 13]);

console.log(VAX);
```

Comment: There is no possible way like `PHP` to `merge` without the need to make three variables?

Comment: You can assign the result to one of the objects: obj2 = Object.assign({}, ob1, obj2)

Comment: Well, For the same one in ajax {data} it requires `{}` to work, I tried `[]` but didn't work.

Comment: If you are working with objects (we need the key and value here, like `{a: 1, b: 2}`), Object.assign is an easy way for merging them. Try to use the first part of my answer

Comment: If you an ordered list without keys (except index) have to use array`[]`. But if you have to reply as JSON it MUST BE an object (so first must be `{}` to be a valid json).. Like so: `var MAX = { values: [1,2,3,4,5]}`. Use `MAX.values` to get the array.

Answer (score 1):

To extend an array with another, just use `Array.prototype.push.apply()`. For example:

```
var VAX = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
if(1 = 1) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(VAX, [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
}
if(x = y) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(VAX, [11, 12, 13]);
}
```

Comment: Humm... didn't know that ! It's very good. But why `a.push([6, 7, 8, 9, 10])` (Add the whole array as single element) havn't the same effect than `Array.prototype.push.apply(a, [6, 7, 8, 9, 10])` (Add all element as now array element) ?!

Comment: @Arthur The `push` method only accepts one array value at a time. So for example, `a.push(6, 7, 8)`. The `apply` method applies an array to a function as arguments. For example, `console.log.apply(null, ["First arg","Second arg"])`. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: Okay thank ! Take care you are using an array `a` instead of `VAX` in your example.